# Unable to resize window on selenium grid 2 nodes

Tags: java, selenium, grid, webdriver

I am unable to resize the Firefox window size on my selenium grid 2 nodes. My nodes are running on ubuntu 12.04 with firefox 15. I am currently using selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar.

It works on my local machine(without selenium grid) where the Firefox resizing to my window size but not on my virtual machine (where I run my nodes). I use this method to maximize windows:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I have tried this method as well but it also doesn't work:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(1920,1080)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
WebDriver driver = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium comes with the ability to modify the window dimensions:

```
driver.manage().window()
            .setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Make sure that you are getting the URL before modifying the window size with .maximize or .setSize.

```
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I recommend that if you are not seeing improvement from these suggestions that you debug your script step-by-step. If it passes over the window re-sizing commands with no errors or other odd behavior then I would be truly stumped.